# Conflicting Python libraries and permanently removing sys.path[0]

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, sys

I have a set of libraries of Python 2.7 that share the same names with some of my project's ones which I can not change.

What I would like to do is to prioritize Python libraries over my own project's libraries.

looking sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as p
>>> p(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/deep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/deep/cocoapi/PythonAPI/Detectron',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycocotools-2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
>>>
```

I see that the libraries in

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
```

should have priority over my project's

```
/home/deep/cocoapi/PythonAPI/Detectron'
```

but it isn't happening, when I run the program I get errors because its tryng to pull the libraries from my project instead of python's libraries.

How can I prioritize this without doing any changes to the files? I wouldn't like to change names o edit the librarie's files. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

***edit** Ok, so the empty string at the beginning of sys.path will be filled with the path containing the executed script. Quoting the manual

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH.

The question would be then, removing `path[0]` will avoid python of checking in the current directory first?
Is it strictly necessary to edit my files and remove `path[0]` before my code?
can I run a command before running my script to clear `path[0]`, somethin like this

```
python -c "import sys; sys.path.pop(0); sys.path.append(''); mypath/myscript.py -myconfig"
```

something similar to that

Comment: Note that the first item of the paths is `''` - your current directory. A namesake module from the current directory will be imported first.

Comment: Also, not directly an answer, but you really should avoid using names in the standard library.

Comment: @KennyOstrom The OP says "which I can not change." The names are probably beyond their control.

Comment: Good point, I missed that.

Comment: @DYZ wow... ok, so removing the empty string '' ' would I be able to prioritize the calls?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: It seems like it is not straight forward. By running `python -c "import sys; sys.path.remove(''); print(sys.path)"` works, but it is not permanent since running `python -c "import sys;  print(sys.path)"` shows it is still there...

Comment: You will certainly need to have it in your python file. Changing it for the whole system is a very bad idea. Even better would be to move it to the end of the path.

Comment: Any idea how to remove it and append it at the end permanently for the whole system? quoting another question `the change to sys.path is not permanent and only affects the current process. If you want to make a change system-wide you'll need to have a look inside the site-packages directory and do some changes` so in other words, edit the `/usr/lib/python2.7/sys.py`. Maybe editing my project's python file to remove only `path[0]`

Comment: Hey @DYZ do you want to post the answer?